# Strumming pattern confusion

Tags: guitar, chords, acoustic-guitar, strumming

I am not sure how to interpret strumming pattern in the picture. I understand that for eights it should be following DUDUDUDU structure but the picture looks like it doesn't make a sense because of U D UDU.

What do I get wrong?

[image: Otherside]

Comment: Check my edit..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks suspect to me. The rhythm of the strumming hand/arm is disturbed. D-D-DUD- would be easier, and probably sound better too. Without listening to it, it's difficult to comment further.

EDIT: having had a quick listen, it's probably D--D-UDU. To keep a constant down/up movement, try DudUdUDU caps are strums, lower case ghost strums. So that second downstrum comes where an upstrum could be, but there's time either side to do it the 'wrong' way.

Comment: Exactly! The pattern you wrote make a sense. I am asking because I didn't expect a mistake (it is official ultimate-guitar notation) but intention. Is it somehow playable as they wrote it? By the easy, the song is Otherside by RHCP.

Comment: @tucna I suspect the transcriber didn't picture actually playing this when they transcribed it and just stuck to strictly alternating down- and up-strokes without really thinking how it would feel to play. Personally if I was playing Otherside, I'd play a rhythm more like `D-DU-UDU` or `D--U--D-`.

Comment: @JamesWhiteley Thank you, I actually sticked with the same rhythm you mentioned :)

Comment: @Tim To your edit - don't you have a video of some strumming pattern like that? I would like to see the guitarist's right hand to be sure I understand it correctly. I have tried to find something by my own but without any success.

Comment: No. Most of us try out the many different patterns till we find one that works for us. There are other ways to learn other than copying.

Comment: @tucna you're welcome. Something you'll learn pretty early on is to take online tutorials with a pinch of salt - it likely won't be 100% accurate so if something doesn't sound/feel right, it's okay to not follow it to the letter (especially on a community-curated site like Ultimate Guitar).

Answer (score -1):

It looks really weird for me,i would play it like D U D D U,well yes  the 8th notes are correctly DUDUDUDU,but you know you dont have to play every single note,in music we have notes and pauses, the notes that are missing are just small pauses,so you should play D(pause) U (pause) DDU in my case,it doesn't matter if you start with a downstroke or with an upstroke,well because you will be in the same time signature in any case,the only thing that changes wether you selecet to start with an Upstroke or a Downstroke is the pattern

Comment: Thank you. I understand a concept of pauses but what you wrote "D(pause)U" - how do you play it? As far as I know, during the strumming you should constantly move your hand DU and (pause) means "don't hit the strings". So "D(move hand but don't hit the strings)U" doesn't make a sense because after (move hand but don't hit the strings) your hand is already "up". Apparently I am missing something.

Comment: Your pattern introduces a 'stutter' which will not be conducive of a smooth hand/arm movement.

Comment: So an 8th note bit in 4/4 is basically 1 & 2 & 3 & 4  the pauses are basically on thr fisrt and second bit, in that pauses imagine that you play a Downstroke but you don't hit it,so you can play like this DDUUDUD but the second D and the fourth U you just imagine that you play it,you dont hit,you just act that you play them to feel the 8th notes,its basically the classic pattern that every new guitar player learn,but in that case you just dont hit the second and the fourth you just act of playing them

Comment: You can also start in 65 bpm instead of 120bpm just to get the feeling

Comment: Also i believe that the tab has written wrong the 8th notes, that has written 1 & 2 & 3 & 4, the & is note but for simplicity we say the word. & Instead of counting to 8 in 4/4 bit,just to not confuse our selves, in that case 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 are 7 notes,they must to be 8 notes thats why we call them 8th notes, so the coreect tab must to be like this 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 &,and then you just keep reapiting,maybe is this the reason that confused you

Comment: Thank you guys. So what you say is that the pattern I mentioned does not expect that I am going to move my hand down and up in a constant tempo and hit the strings from time to time, but more like "move up and hit the strings, wait 1/8 (it means do not move the hand down in a "silent move"), move down and hit the strings" ?

Comment: Yes,i think you got it

Comment: @Gamerpew619 - care to check in your 1st comment. Looks like 5/4 to me.

Comment: Well i think i just missed a note, sorry my bad XD